# How to change permalink on headlines in rss feeds?

Tags: custom-field, filters, rss, feed

On mysite.com/feed the headlines of my posts listed in the feed are linked to that posts permalink, for example mysite.com/my-first-post. This is standard behaviour.
But sometimes I would like this link not to be the post permalink but a link to page I've specified in a custom field inside that post, it could be for example an external link like apple.com or whatever.

How can I change the rss feed headline link?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using Custom RSS Feed method very well explained by Joost ( For reference: http://yoast.com/custom-rss-feeds-wordpress/ ). Using this way, you can display any of the fields either custom field value or featured image.

Comment: So it's not possible to just hook on to the standard WP feed template and change that?

Comment: you have to start editing some of wordpress files for doing this. So, the best and clean way for doing this is to create a separate template for displaying custom RSS Feed.

Comment: Ok I don't want to edit any core WP files. But what if I want my custom template to be shown in mysite.com/feed – do I have to make a redirect from that URL to the page where my custom template resides or is it possible to tell WP to use my custom template instead of the regular WP template?

Comment: You can create a wp page named "feed" and assign this custom template to it. This will work.

Comment: That seems a bit ugly and unfortunately (or maybe it's a good thing) it doesn't seem to work, the slug automatically change into 'feed-2' when i create a page called 'Feed'. Thanks anyway! But there must be a better way to do this, please let me know if you have any other ideas.